# Bacon.jsで後続のアキュムレータをスキップする方法について

Tags: javascript

Bacon.jsでアキュームレータ関数を複数設定し、関数の結果しだいで後続の関数をスキップすることはできるのでしょうか？

```
let bus = new Bacon.Bus();
bus.map(accume1)  // ここの処理によってはaccume2をスキップしてaccume3の処理を行いたい
   .map(accume2)
   .map(accume3);
bus.push(1);
```

どういう風にすればできるのか。
また、そもそもアキュームレータで分岐をさせたいというのはBacon.js的に正しいことなのか教えてください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

フロー制御には、[observable.takeWhile(property)](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#observable-takewhile) もしくは、 [observable.flatMap(f)](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#observable-flatmap) が使えます。 `flatMap` を使うことになると思いますが、「スキップして実行させる」というよりも、「途中で、以降に通すストリームを定義する」形になります。

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

$("#source").text(arr.join(', '));

$("#run").click(function() {
    var stream = Bacon.sequentially(250, arr);
    var acc_power = function(x) {
        return x*x;
    };
    var acc_1k = function(x) {
        return x + 1000;
    };
    $("#result").text("");
    stream
        .takeWhile( function(x){ return x <= 8; }) // この時点の x が 8 より大きければスキップ
        .map( acc_power)
        .flatMap(function(x) {
            // この時点の x で処理を分ける
            return (x > 30) ? Bacon.once(x).map(acc_1k) : x;
        })
    .onValue(function(val) {
            $("#result").append(val + ", ");
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bacon.js/0.7.49/Bacon.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Source</h3>
<p id="source"></p>
<hr/>
<button id="run">Run</button><hr/>
<h3>Result</h3>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: `takeWhile`と`flatMap`の使い分けについての確認です。
`takeWhile`はsubscribeしているところまでスキップして、`flatMap`は分岐で違うstreamを戻すことで通るstreamを変えるという認識で良いでしょうか？

Comment: どちらも、 関数を渡すことで条件式の評価が行えますが、評価後に、「`takeWhile` / `skipWhile` では 終了もしくは続行」 「`flatMap` では 任意の処理」をすることに違いがあります。  `flatMap` で `takeWhile` と同じ様なことをするには、  `Bacon.once(x)` か  `Bacon.never()` を返せば良いでしょう。  `flatMap` に渡した関数は、その時点に挟むストリームの生成処理であって、ここで別のストリームをそのまま渡してもかまいません。 様々な用途に使えるので、Nyamazing さんの例のように終了の仕方も考えていろいろ試してみると良いと思います。

Answer (score 2):

Yamamotoさんの示すとおりflatMapを使うか、あるいはfilterでストリームを分ける方法が使えると思います。

また、Promiseのthenやcatchのような用途を想定しているのであれば、
Bacon.Errorを使って、onErrorやmapErrorでキャッチするという方法もあります。

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

$("#source").text(arr.join(', '));

$("#run").click(function() {
    var stream = Bacon.sequentially(250, arr);
    var acc_power = function(x) {
        return x*x;
    };
    var acc_1k = function(x) {
        return x + 1000;
    };
    $("#result").text("");
    var s = stream
        .map( acc_power)
        .flatMap(function(x) {
            // 30より小さい場合はエラー
            return (x < 30) ? new Bacon.Error(x) : x;
        })
        .map(acc_1k).map(acc_1k); // エラーの場合、この処理は飛ばされる

    // 正常な場合
    var unsub = s.onValue(function(val) {
            $('<p>',{text:val}).appendTo("#result");
        });

    // エラーの場合
    var unsub_e = s.onError(function(err) {
            $('<p>',{text:err + ' is too small'}).appendTo("#result");
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bacon.js/0.7.49/Bacon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Source</h3>
<p id="source"></p>
<hr/>
<button id="run">Run</button><hr/>
<h3>Result</h3>
<p id="result"></p>
```